# White insects on tomato plant?

Tags: tomatoes

There are a lot of white insects on my tomato plants Lower base stem and some on leaves I wonder they useful or should I kill them or if they bad what are they called and how to to get rid of them. [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice photos, especially the last one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is scale or mealybug, they are insects that suck sap out of the plant. So yes they are harmful and it is better for your plant to get rid of them.

There are several ways to get rid of them (in my opinion there is no best way), the easiest is to rub them off the plant or spray with soap. Also poisons are available, but none of the methods are 100% effective (that is my experience with scale insects).

[Here](https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Scale-Insects) some instructions and more info.

Comment: ohooo :( they have destroyed my tomato plant heads :( looks like i have to plant them again ... i have sprayed soap water on them hope it will kill them